# Forzar crear sesión en php

Tags: php, html

Tengo una aplicación web que trabaja con sesiones de usuarios

Tengo una versión móvil de esta aplicación, que para utilizarla requiere iniciar sesión, pero a veces al minimizar la app y volver a abrirla, creo que se pierde la sesión, aunque aparezco como "logueado" y puedo utilizarla sin problema. A veces en el **error_log** me aparece

```html
Undefined variable: _SESSION in ..................
```

La forma que tengo de verificar sesión es la siguiente

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 include 'functions.php';
 verificar_sesion();
 ?>
```

**Y este es el archivo functions.php**

```html
<?php

function verificar_sesion(){
  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    unset($_SESSION);
    header("location: index.php");
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Podrías guardar la apertura de sesión en una cookie y si no detecta la sesión volver a crearla desde la cookie. Cuando se deslogue borras la cookie.

Comment: unset($_SESSION); si la session no existe no es necesario el unset();